# Safari complains: Origin file:// is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: safari, http-headers, httpwebrequest

My JavaScript Ajax program works fine with FireFox.
It even works OK on iPad!

But when I run it on Safari on Windows 7 - I get the above error.
I am attaching the HttpRequest header and respond.

First the FF data- see below - 
I think - not sure - that it shows that the site I am accessing is not blocking me.

Next is the Safari data- see below - 
I think that the problem is that Safari adds to the request header a
Origin:file://

I am not sure that this is the problem and I did not find a way to force Safari not to add it.

Thanks for your help
Ori

### Here is the FF Data

Response Headers
Date    Thu, 04 Aug 2011 19:08:58 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.3 (Linux/SUSE)
Keep-Alive  timeout=15, max=100
Connection  Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Content-Type    text/html

Request Headers
Host    www.arabdictionary.huji.ac.il
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.18) Gecko/20110614 BTRS35926 Firefox/3.6.18
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length  50
Pragma  no-cache
Cache-Control   no-cache

### Safari data

Request URL:http://www.arabdictionary.huji.ac.il/cgi-bin/arabic_results.pl
Request Headers
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
DNT:1
Origin:file://   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< I think that this is my problem <<<<<<<<<<<<<
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 4_3_3 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8J2 Safari/6533.18.5

Form Data
String:%d4%d4 
searchType:byElement
act:dosearch

<<<<<<<<<<< No more data - no Response >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Comment: I just run a sniffer<BR>To my confusion the sniffer shows an "200 OK" plus the COMPLETE server responds<BR>But Safari insists on the above err<BR>(And the http_req.responseText is empty)<BR>I will post the details in the next comment